# Display data loading with delay

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

i have a asp:table with 0(zero) rows and button on my page.

when user clicks the button, it add five rows into the table and show them on the page.

but i want to show each row with some delay on page.

sequence should be like this : once a rows is added then show the loading image then add another rows ,then loading Image,then add row and so on

Comment: Have you considered the necessity for this? Users want a fast, responsive experience- it seems you are putting effort into preventing that.

Comment: actually the scenario is this: i have different services name in the db, i get their name and check that whether they are running or not. My page shows the result of all services at once but i need to show them step by step

Answer (score 0):

i have used the timer and threading to acheive the result and for better user experience ajax update panel

My Main thread start a new thread for each record and completes the User interface.i had a timer on page that checks the status of each row and updates the data as the relevant thread for that row is completed.